# Editing article in Joomla 3.2 SQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

When I want to **Save** currently editing article i have this error:

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `sha1_hash` = '2767de6c4360cd17f82bc9fe15203dbd6337c785' LIMIT 0, 1' at line 3 SQL=SELECT * FROM `pdg_ucm_history` WHERE `ucm_item_id` = 103 AND `ucm_type_id` = AND `sha1_hash` = '2767de6c4360cd17f82bc9fe15203dbd6337c785' LIMIT 0, 1 "
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Ok, and are you using the default Joomla article manager or a 3rd party extension to manage your articles?

Comment: Default joomla article manager. This error appeared one day ago, earlier everythik was find.

Comment: Have you installed any extensions in the last couple of days that might have caused this? Also, try repairing the database tables that are mentioned in the error

Comment: This table what is error is empty, repair don't help. Is possible to repair by joomla admin panel?

Comment: In the Joomla backend, try going to **Extensions** >> **Extension Manager** >> **Database** and check everything is up to date

Comment: I have got error here. Database is not up to date. But I turn off Articles versioning and it works now.

Comment: It might be possible that there is a bug with Article Versioning. I will ask about this ;)

Comment: Thanks for help. You can write answer about versioning error and I will approve it :)

Comment: if database is not up to date just click the fix button and it will be.

Comment: There is no fix button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your MySQL version and ensure it corresponds to the Joomla 3.x requirements.
2. Try repairing the database tables as mentioned in the error you received.
3. In the Joomla backend, try going to **Extensions** >> **Extension Manager** >> **Database** and check everything is up to date. If it says it is not up to date, click the Fix button.
4. It could be a possible bug with Joomla's Article versioning which I have already asked about and waiting reply

Comment: There aren't any known bugs. If the steps above don't fix your issue post a bug (issue) report on the github page for Joomla here https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms and we'll try and figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this myself.

The value for ucm_type_id is not being added to the sql, hence the broken syntax.  Joomla grabs this data from the content_types table, so check that and verify that you have an entry for the type of content you're attempting to save.

For some reason I was missing a bunch of the basics, like "Article".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is only an interim solution, but I have just experienced the same problem showing a SQL syntax error when attempting to save an article in J3.3.6. It seems that the article versioning which I had just discovered and enabled is causing this error. It disappeared once I disabled the article history option.

Answer (score -1):

It perhaps due to missing records in content_types table.

I left a comment in this thread.

https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/7598